# Import an existing database in iOS

Tags: ios, database, macos, sqlite

I have an existing database on SQLite3.
How I can import this database into XCode and work with data?

Is it possible to work with SQLite3 without using Core Data?

I have never encountered this problem and in other forums I I didn't understand.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is available for iOS and OSX. The C API library is provided by Apple. You don't need core data. Just use the C API to work with the sqlite database or use an Objective-C wrapper such as FMDB.

Just add your existing database to the project like any other resource file.

Under iOS, if you need to write to the database you will need to copy the database file at runtime from the app's bundle to a writable folder. Do this the 1st time the app runs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If the answer solved your question, click on the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not answer your question, but I think you can find this really helpful..

this is a framework I found on the internet to work with sqlite databases..

https://github.com/enormego/egodatabase

GL HF